# There is no active transaction'

Tags: php, laravel-8

having problems with this function `wipe_data`

this `wipe_data` function my DB cleanup and admin data inserting
but this function shows error:

> There is no active transaction

This is my code:

```
 function wipe_data() {
     DB::beginTransaction();
     $adminData = User::where('role', 'admin')->first();  
    try {
        User::truncate();
        User_details::truncate();
        User_kyc::truncate();
        Token::truncate();`enter code here`
        $auto_id = date('Y');
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE ls_users AUTO_INCREMENT = $auto_id");
        $admin = new User();
        $admin->username = $adminData->username;
        $admin->email = $adminData->email;
        $admin->password = $adminData->password;
        $admin->role = $adminData->role;
        $admin->save();
        $user_id = User::where('role', 'admin')->value('id');
        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        DB::rollback();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are some [statements that caused implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html), including the `ALTER TABLE` statement you are using.

Therefore, your statement has already been committed before you called `DB::commit()`, hence an error occurred.